# How to group the records based to 3rd table belongs to, has many

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have below code:

quiz.rb

```
has_many :quiz_attempts
```

student.rb

```
has_many :quiz_attempts
```

quiz_attempt.rb

```
belongs_to :student
belongs_to :quiz
```

What I need to do is to get all records of student from quiz_attempts table which has quiz id and show the records of quiz table based on it.

Means, if students has taken one quiz A 10 times and quiz B 5 times, so I need to show all these rows as 2 from quiz table.

In view I will have only 2 records of quiz table which are associated with 15 records of A and B collectively in quiz_attempts table.

quiz_attempts has `quiz_id` column and student_id column as well, quiz table has no student id in it.

The query I am working with is:

```
@quizzes   = @student.quiz_attempts.includes(:quiz)
```

but the problem is that, it still shows me 2 rows but from quiz_attempts table and I cant group them as quiz table.

I need to have complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Quiz.joins(quiz_attempts: :student)
    .where.not(students: { id: nil })
    .group('quizzez.id')
```

What above does is basically the following:

1. `Quiz.joins(quiz_attempts: :student)` - select all rows from `quizzes` table, which have connection with `quiz_attempts` and `students` tables.
2. `.where.not(students: { id: nil })` from above select only those quizzes, which have students who has taken `quiz_attempts`.
3. `.group('quizzez.id')` says that we do not want to have the same quiz shown multiple times because lots of students have attempted to pass it, but only uniq records.

## EDIT

As discussed in comments, to have above query be based on `current_user`'s id, you could implement a AR [scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope):

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_student_id, lambda { |student_id|
    joins(quiz_attempts: :student).where(students: { id: student_id }).group('quizzez.id')
  }
end
```

To use this scope you'd write:

```
Quiz.by_student_id(current_user.id)
```

Comment: Not working, it still shows 15 rows from quiz table. it does shows records from quiz table but they are 15 in numbers. It should be only 2 records as associated 15 are in quiz_attempts table.

Comment: @LearningROR you then will have to group by quizzez.id column, edited the answer

Comment: Could you please explain that query as well to me? So, I will have the reason of its working too. :)

Comment: @LearningROR edited the answer, I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much, it really works for my current scenario :) The explanations really helped me understanding query :)

Comment: @LearningROR glad to help)

Comment: I am sorry, but query might have one problem. I wanted to get all these records based on current user id. could we add that too? Basically, currently its working as general query but we need to use that on student profile so I am asking, i was trying using that based on `@student`

Comment: @LearningROR yea, we can do that. it would be a scope with student_id as a parameter. Let me edit the answer

Comment: Yes that really works. Thanks so much polish guy. 
I really admire the talent of Poland. :)

Comment: @LearningROR I am Ukrainian :D It's just that I live in Poland lately, but you are welcome anyway :)

Comment: Haha. ;) My bad, but you got talent bro ;) thanks for all help.